# How to tell if broadcast received Android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-shortcut

I'm creating a shortcut by sending out this broadcast.

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, AuthenticationActivity.class);
    // create the broadcast
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, widget.name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, widget.resourceId));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I'm wondering is there a way to know if the broadcast was received by the launcher? I display a toast to the user saying the shortcut was created successfully but some launchers may not support this.